# codebuild shows in progress even after the test passed

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm building a CI/CD pipeline using git, codebuild and elastic beanstalk.

During codebuild execution when all tests passed, I see codebuild's  build stage remains "in progress". I had to manually stop the codebuild's execution.

I'm assuming I have to pass exit code from my mocha tests, but do not know how to.

Please see the buildspec below.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing package.json..
      - npm install
      - echo Installing Mocha...
      - npm install -g mocha
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM placeholder dependencies...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Compiling the Node.js code
      - mocha modules/**/tests/*.js
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - modules/*
    - node_modules/*
    - package.json
    - config/*
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding an exit flag to the Mocha command

I added a flag --exit to mocha like this

```
mocha --exit modules/**/tests/*.js
```

Build stage expect an exit code. Adding a --exit flag provides this exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Please note there is a short delay between when CodeBuild build finishes and when it appears as completed on CodePipeline, in case that is what you're running into.